# how to configure QLineEdit in pyautogui.typewrite

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use Qtdesigner and then convert it to py file..I want to take input text through the QLineEdit and put it to pyautogui.typewrite. facing problem to solve it.

I write the the code bleow

[image]

```
import pyautogui
import time
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
from messageRHR import Ui_MainWindow
class MainThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self,message):
        super(MainThread,self).__init__()
        # self.message = QLineEdit(self)
        
    def run(self):
        self.taskExecution()
            
    def taskExecution(self):
        pyautogui.typewrite(message)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('Enter')
startExecution = MainThread()
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startTask)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
    def startTask(self):
        self.ui.movie = QtGui.QMovie("00545cb7179c504433d4c8f5e845f286.gif")
        self.ui.label_2.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
        self.ui.movie.start()
        self.ui.movie = QtGui.QMovie("00545cb7179c504433d4c8f5e845f286.gif")
        self.ui.label_3.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
        self.ui.movie.start()
        message = QLineEdit(self)
        startExecution.start()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
rsn = Main()
rsn.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: May I ask you what do you need pyautogui for in your program?

Comment: Your question is unclear, For example if the user writes hello then what should be written with pyautogui ¿"h", "e", "l", "l" y "o" or "h", "he", "hel" , "hell", "hello"?

Comment: I want to automate the message sending in facebook

Comment: @Ramesh Could you answer what I have asked you? Please use `@username`